# c# / XAML highlight row in listbox that matches parent data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have the following listbox -- the overall Datacontext goes to the class BatchRef

```
<ListBox x:Name="Details"
     ItemsSource="{Binding BatchRef.ScheduleGroups}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                   <localData:ScheduleGroupControl></localData:ScheduleGroupControl>
             </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

BatchRef has an CurrentID field, and the ScheduleGroup Class has an ID field.  I am looking for a way to determine if a ScheduleGroup ID field matches the CurrentID on the BatchRef field.  One of the listbox items will always be a match to the parent, and I need to highlight the correct row.

Comment: style with a data trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DataTrigger` to do this.

Something like this in your `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Current.Groups}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentId,
                                            StringFormat={}CurrentID: {0}}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Current.CurrentId,
                                            StringFormat={}ParentID: {0}, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}"/>

                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IntEqualConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="CurrentId"/>
                                        <Binding Path="DataContext.Current.CurrentId"
                                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                </DataTrigger.Setters>                   
                            </DataTrigger>                                        
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I've used a `IMultiValueConverter` to check if the two values are equal:

```
public class IntEqualConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.OfType<int>().Distinct().Count() == 1;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This is a crude example. But it should point you in the right direction.

The important things to note are:

- You need to use `RelativeSource` on the binding otherwise the DataContext will be that of the `ListBoxItem`, not your view's `DataContext`.
- You will need to add the converter as a resource.

[image: Example]

If it helps to understand. The `Current` property on my `ViewModel` is a `BatchRef` Object. The `BatchRef` class has a property called `Groups` which of type `ObservableCollection<ScheduleGroup>`.

Comment: thank you -- that looks like enough to go on -- your example is very thorough!

Comment: No problem. Let me know if there are any issues and I will see if I can help.